# Ruby: turn each into collect

Tags: ruby

Each `lecture` has a `stars` representing its rating, from 1 to 5, and I want to select the `sub_lectures` with `stars >= 5`. Here is what I've done:

```
  sub_lectures = []
  lectures.each do |lec|
    sub_lectures << lec if lec[:stars] >= 5
  end
  @lectures = sub_lectures
```

But I think this is quite inelegant. I know there is a `collect` method, which could return `array` by default.

How can I use `collect` to simplify my code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're looking for the select method.

```
@lectures = lectures.select {|l| l[:stars} >= 5}
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution using `collect`:

```
@lectures = lectures.collect { |lec| lec if lec[:stars] >= 5 }.compact
```

Without calling `compact` the result array would contain `nil` values for the lectures that does not satisfy the condition. The solution using `select` is the actually the best one.